# Is it possible to create a spin the wheel app that has random wins after every 5 spins

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a wheel of prizes (spin the wheel). I am building the app on react and using this package;

```
react-wheel-of-prizes
```

I would like for the wheel to be in such a way that there is a winner for every 5 spins. The position of the winner between 1 and 5 should be random, eg, if in the first 5 people to spin the winner is the second spinner, the next 5 spinners should get the winner from 4, 5, 3 or 1.
This is my wheel component:

```
    <WheelComponent
      segments={segments}
      segColors={segColors}
      winningSegment="MM"
      onFinished={(winner) => onFinished(winner)}
      primaryColor="#5C0632"
      contrastColor="gray"
      buttonText="Start"
      isOnlyOnce={false}
      size={280}
      upDuration={500}
      downDuration={600}
      fontFamily="Helvetica"
    />
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After each spin random number is generated between 1-5 which never repeats

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import WheelComponent from 'react-wheel-of-prizes';

    const segments = [
  'better luck next time',
  'won 70',
  'won 10',
  'better luck next time',
  'won 2',
  'won uber pass',
  'better luck next time',
  'won a voucher'
]
const segColors = [
  '#EE4040',
  '#F0CF50',
  '#815CD1',
  '#3DA5E0',
  '#34A24F',
  '#F9AA1F',
  '#EC3F3F',
  '#FF9000'
]

function MyWheelComponent() {

  const [alreadyWinArray, setAlreadyWinArray] = useState([]);
  const [winnerPosition, setWinnerPosition] = useState(null);
  const [spinCount, setSpinCount] = useState(0);
  const [spinCompleted,setSpinCompleted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (spinCount > 0) {
      if (spinCount % 2 === 0) {           
        let randomPosition = generateRandom();
        setSpinCount(0);
        setWinnerPosition(randomPosition);
        setAlreadyWinArray([...alreadyWinArray,randomPosition]);
      }
    }
  }, [spinCount])


  useEffect(()=>{

    if(alreadyWinArray.length >=5){
      setSpinCompleted(true);
    }

  },[alreadyWinArray])


  const generateRandom = () => {
    const randomPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
    if (alreadyWinArray.includes(randomPosition) == true) {
     return generateRandom();
    } else {
      return randomPosition;
    }
  }


  const handleSpinFinished = (winner) => {
    setSpinCount((prevSpinCount) => prevSpinCount + 1);
  };



  const onFinished = (winner) => {
    console.log(winner)
  }

  return (
    !spinCompleted ? <WheelComponent
      segments={segments}
      segColors={segColors}
      winningSegment="MM"
      onFinished={handleSpinFinished}
      primaryColor="#5C0632"
      contrastColor="gray"
      buttonText="Start"
      isOnlyOnce={false}
      size={280}
      upDuration={500}
      downDuration={600}
      fontFamily="Helvetica"
    />
    :
    <>Spin Over! Winner List are {alreadyWinArray.map((item)=>{ return (<>{item},</>) })}</>
  );
};

export default MyWheelComponent;
```